# Could I use selfhost AD with OpenPAI?

Tags: openpai

For some reasons, our servers cannot connect to the Internet so we have a selfhost AD server to manage users. I wonder if I could use it because the docs only say they support AAD :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to self-host AAD.

Except for AAD, OpenPAI provides also [basic authentication mode](https://openpai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/cluster-admin/how-to-manage-users-and-groups.html#basic-authentication-mode), which you can use without internet access.

As a reference, there are tools like [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-azure-ad-connect) that can help to sync your on-prem & cloud auth system.